# ¿Cómo trazar la distancia de Manhattan entre dos puntos usando pyplot?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

Necesito unir dos puntos con el módulo pyplot, pero que esa unión se visualice como la distancia de Manhattan (ver https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometr%C3%ADa_del_taxista) entre dichos puntos.

He conseguido unir dos puntos con una línea:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[2,5]
y=[2,5]
plt.axis([0,8,0,8])
plt.plot(x,y,'.-')
plt.pause(3)
plt.close()
```

pero la linea que se dibuja entre estos puntos es una linea recta que va desde ***p1*** a ***p2***, cuando yo necesito que se dibuje como dos lineas que se interceptan en en forma de "L" en las coordenadas que ambos puntos coincidan.

Comment: Saludos Leandro L, bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español, por curiosidad, ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Saludos, ya uní dos puntos por ejemplo, p1(2,2)y p2(5,5), la linea que se dibuja entre estos puntos es una linea recta que va desde p1 a p2 pero necesito que se dibuje como dos lineas que se intersectan en en forma de L es decir en las coordenadas que ambos puntos coincidan, esto es de gran necesidad ya que es para respesentar informacion en mi tesis, saludos

Comment: @LeandroL podrías pegar el código que tenes hecho hasta ahora? Es mucho más fácil ayudarte de esa forma.

Comment: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[2,5]
y=[2,5]

plt.axis([0,8,0,8])
plt.plot(x,y,'.-')
plt.pause(3)
plt.close()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal y como lo haces obtienes una línea recta que une ambos puntos, la distancia euclidiana. Al menos que yo sepa, no hay nada preconstruido en Matplotlib que permita unir dos puntos usando la geometría Taxicab.

Lo que puedes hacer es simplemente calcular el o los vértices tu mismo, lógicamente, existen múltiples posibilidades a la hora de unir dos puntos de esta forma, lo más simple sería:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


p1 = (2, 2)
p2 = (5, 5)

plt.axis([0, 8, 0, 8])
plt.plot((p1[0], p2[0], p2[0]), (p1[1], p1[1], p2[1]), '.-', markevery=(0, 2))
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


p1 = (2, 2)
p2 = (5, 5)

plt.axis([0, 8, 0, 8])
plt.plot((p1[0], p1[0], p2[0]), (p1[1], p2[1], p2[1]), '.-', markevery=(0, 2))
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El argumento `markevery` permite definir que puntos queremos que muestren la marca correspondiente, en este caso solo queremos que se muestren los puntos `p1` y `p2`, pero no el vértice. Se le pasa una lista con los índices de los puntos que queremos que se muestren.